# flow type for an array of option elements from react

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a function that returns an array of react `<option>` elements:

```
function mapOptionToValues(
  element: any,
  valueKey: ?string,
  optionKey: ?string
): React$Element<*> {
  if (!valueKey && !optionKey) {
    return (
      <option key={element}>
        {element}
      </option>
    );
  }

  return (
    <option value={element[valueKey]} key={element[valueKey]}>
      {element[optionKey]}
    </option>
  );
}
```

But I get this error:

```
<option value={element[valueKey]} key={element[valueKey]}>
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ React element `option`
 24:     <option value={element[valueKey]} key={element[valueKey]}>
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `value`. Property not found in
 17:       <option key={element}>
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ props of React element `option`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that React.Element<*> tries to infer the exact type of the component, including its Props, but the two possible returns of your function have different Props.

If you remove the React.Element<*> type from your code, flow will infer it for you as a more general `JSX.Element`, that will accept both cases.